# iOS how to get the width of entire row in tableview cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to color left half of the cell to be green and right half of the cell to be red. Before commenting `cell.frame.width` PLEASE check the code snippet [HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTFQw.png)  I have done and the result I get. We can notice that there is some white space trailing. My guess is that `cell.frame` is not giving me the correct frame I need.

Any help or other approach which can achieve the same result is greatly appreciated!

UPDATE: the table view and contraints [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uwdxa.png)

Comment: Try cell.contentView.frame.size.width.

Comment: did. that is the same as 'cell.frame.size.width'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better use auto layout, it will make application to work in both orientation.

And also in your implementation the bgView will created every time when cellForRowAtIndexPath method is called for each cell, so better check if bgView is nil than only create the bgView.
Please refer the below code.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellID", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    if cell.backgroundView == nil {

        let leftView = UIView()
        let rightView = UIView()
        rightView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        leftView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
        cell.backgroundView = UIView()
        cell.backgroundView?.addSubview(leftView)
        cell.backgroundView?.addSubview(rightView)
        leftView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
        rightView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;

        let viewDict = ["leftView":leftView, "rightView":rightView]

        cell.backgroundView!.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-0-[leftView]-0-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewDict))
        cell.backgroundView!.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-0-[rightView]-0-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewDict))

        cell.backgroundView!.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-0-[leftView]-0-[rightView(==leftView)]-0-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewDict))

    }

    cell.textLabel?.text = "dsfsdkjfh fkjhsdkjfhs kdfksdhfk sdf";
    return cell

}
```

Comment: thank you so much. work like a charm. even though I am lost after addsubview...LOL but I just copy and paste it

Answer (score 1):

This could be do to many reasons. A couple things you could try:

The cell may be making room for accessory views, such as the check mark, arrow, etc. Try setting the cell's accessory type to .None:

```
cell.accessoryType = .None
```

Rather than adding a view for the right side, try setting the cell's background color instead, then setting the left side to view.width/2

```
cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor
let leftViewFrame = cell.bounds
leftViewFrame.width = view.frame.width / 2.0
let leftView = UIView(frame: leftViewFrame)
```

Another potential issue can be solved with this in viewDidLoad:

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
```

Comment: good catch on creating just a view and add it on instead of two. after I follow your way the trailing white space is gone because of the background of cell is changed entire. However, the size of green part is still the same.

Comment: odd...I added another potential fix to my answer, are you sure the size of the view isn't changing for some reason? You could potentially test this by reloading the tableview in viewDidAppear